# how to get entry field as a password (*) in notebook tab pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I have used gtk.Notebook() in my script, In notebook tab I have given 2 text fields username and password but problem is that the entry field does not behave as password field, it is showing character. so I want if i type password it should be confidential jsut like as (*).

This is code which i have used

```
    entry = gtk.Entry()
    entry.set_invisible_char("*")
    entry.set_size_request(100, 75)
    entry.show ()

    label = gtk.Label("Add page")
    notebook.insert_page(entry, label, 2)
```

Now anyone tell me how to do that.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gtk Entry documentation:

> [gtk_entry_set_visibility()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-visibility) sets whether the contents of the entry are visible or not. When visibility is set to FALSE, characters are displayed as the invisible char, and will also appear that way when the text in the entry widget is copied elsewhere.

For python that should be `Entry.set_visibility(False)`.

Also, you don't need to set the invisible character: GTK+ will do it's best to pick a good character for the font in question (typically '*').

Comment: Thanks @jku it's working but same problem is occurring in renderer = gtk.CellRendererText(), here how to do that password confidential

Comment: You'll have to implement that yourself,  I'm afraid.